# Find a $2$-Sylow subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_3(F_7)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, sylow-theory

We have $|\mathrm{GL}_3(F_7)| = 7^3 \cdot 2^6\cdot 3^4\cdot 19$. I can find the $3,7,19$-Sylow subgroup of it, but failed to find a $2$-Sylow subgroup. Can one help?

Comment: Do you know words like "torus" and the embedding of the multiplicative group fo fields in GL? I can give a short answer if you do.

Comment: @JackSchmidt, I thought I know the embedding thing, but not sure about the torus. Doesn't it a geometrical concept?...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Short version:** $
\newcommand{\GF}[1]{\mathbb{F}_{#1}}
\newcommand{\GL}{\operatorname{GL}}
\newcommand{\Gal}{\operatorname{Gal}}
\newcommand{\Sym}[1]{\operatorname{Sym}(#1)}
\newcommand{\bm}[5]{\left[\begin{array}{r|rr} #1 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline 0 & #2 & #3 \\ 0 & #4 & #5 \end{array}\right]}
$A Sylow 2-subgroup is a direct product of the Sylow 2-subgroup of $\GF{7}^\times$ with the Sylow 2-subgroup of $\Gal(\GF{49}/\GF{7}) \ltimes \GF{49}^\times$.

Remember that the Galois group of $\GF{49}$ acts $\GF{7}$-linearly on $\GF{49}$. Similarly $\GF{49}^\times$ (and $\GF{7}^\times$) act $\GF{7}$-linearly on $\GF{49}$ (and $\GF{7}$ respectively). Thus those groups end up acting on $\GF{7} \times \GF{49} \cong \GF{7}^3$.

**Explicit version:** In terms of matrices, that is $$
\bm{-1}{1}{0}{0}{1}, \qquad
\bm{1}{1}{0}{-1}{-1}, \qquad
\bm{1}{0}{1}{1}{-1}$$

We split the matrices into block matrices. The top-left $1 \times 1$ block is $\GF{7}$.  The bottom-right $2\times 2$ block is $\GF{49}$.

The first matrix generates the Sylow 2-subgroup of $\GF{7}^\times$, the second matrix is the Frobenius automorphism of $\GF{49}$, and the last generates the Sylow 2-subgroup of $\GF{49}^\times$ of order 16. Here I choose a basis of $\GF{49}$ of the form $\{1,\xi\}$ where $\xi$ is a primitive $16$th root of unity in $\GF{49}$. For a choice that makes the second matrix prettier, see below.

**Intuitive version:**

I'll repeatedly use a simple but useful fact: If $H \leq G$ are finite, and $p$ does not divide the index $[G:H]$, then every Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. I'll choose $H$ so that we can use induction. I'll try to describe all Sylow $p$-subgroups for all prime powers $q$, but I'll ignore $p$ divides $q$ (upper unitriangulars form a Sylow $p$-subgroup in this case), and I'll assume $q$ is odd to make a few statements smoother.

I put a [more complete version](http://www.ms.uky.edu/~jack/2013-06-24-SylowsOfGL3.pdf) on my website.

The order of $\GL(3,q)$ is $(q^3-1)(q^3-q)(q^3-q^2) = q^3(q-1)^3(q+1)(q^2+q+1)$ with the latter factorization driving most of the case by case analysis. The main subgroups we consider are $\GF{q}^\times \cong \GL(1,q)$, $\GF{q^2}^\times \leq \GL(2,q)$, and $\GL(1,q) \times \GL(1,q) \times \GL(1,q) \leq \GL(1,q) \times \GL(2,q) \leq \GL(3,q)$.

Assume $q$ is an odd prime power. Then $[\GL(3,q):\GL(1,q) \times \GL(2,q)] = q^2(q^2+q+1)$.  For many primes $p$, a Sylow $p$-subgroup is contained in $\GL(1,q) \times \GL(2,q)$. The exceptions are those $p$ such that $q$ has order 3 mod $p$, and of course the defining characteristic where $p$ divides $q$. At any rate, if $q$ is odd, then $p=2$ does not divide $q^2(q^2+q+1) \equiv 1 \mod 2$, so a Sylow 2-subgroup is contained in $\GL(1,q) \times \GL(2,q)$.

Thus we want the direct product of a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $\GL(1,q)$ and a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $\GL(2,q)$, at least for our $p=2$.

The Sylow 2-subgroup of $\GL(1,q)\cong \GF{q}^\times$ is isomorphic to the Sylow 2-subgroup of $\GF{q}^\times$. In case $q=7$, it is generated by $\begin{bmatrix}-1\end{bmatrix}$ of order 2. In general, I'll just call $\zeta$ a generator of the Sylow $p$-subgroup of $\GF{q}^\times$.

The Sylow 2-subgroup of $\GL(2,q)$ comes in two varieties. The index $[\GL(2,q):\Sym{2} \ltimes (\GL(1,q) \times \GL(1,q))] = q(1+q)/2$, so assuming $p$ does not divide $q$ (automatic if $q$ is odd and $p=2$) and $p$ does not divide $(1+q)/2$ (for $p=2$ and $q$ odd this just means $1 \equiv q \mod 4$), then the Sylow $p$-subgroup is contained in $\Sym{2} \ltimes (\GL(1,q) \times \GL(1,q))$.

In such a case, $1 \equiv q \mod 4$, the full Sylow 2-subgroup is generated by the matrices:

$$
\bm{\zeta}{1}{0}{0}{1}, \qquad
\bm{1}{0}{1}{1}{0}, \qquad
\bm{1}{\zeta}{0}{0}{1}
$$

In the other case, $3 \equiv q \mod 4$, view $\GF{q}^2$ as $\GF{q^2}$ by choosing a basis. I suggest choosing a basis $\{x,x^q\}$ so that the linear transformation $\GF{q^2} \to \GF{q^2}:t \mapsto t^q$ is represented by the matrix $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$. Now choose $\xi \in \GF{q^2}$ a generator of the Sylow $p$-subgroup of $\GF{q^2}^\times$. Multiplication by $\xi$ is a $\GF{q}$-linear map of $\GF{q^2}$, so it has a matrix, denote it $A$. At any rate, $[\GL(2,q):\Gal(\GF{q^2}/\GF{q})\ltimes \GF{q^2}^\times] = q(q-1)/2$ and since $3 \equiv q \mod 4$, $p=2$ does not divide this index.

In this case, $3 \equiv q \mod 4$, the full Sylow 2-subgroup is generated by the matrices:

$$\bm{\zeta}{1}{0}{0}{1}, \qquad
\bm{1}{0}{1}{1}{0}, \qquad
\left[\begin{array}{r|r} 1 & 0 \\ \hline 0 & A \end{array}\right]
$$

In the explicit answer above, I chose a different basis of $\GF{q^2}$, $\{1,\eta\}$, and with respect to this basis $A$ has matrix $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\1&-1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ because the minimum polynomial of $\eta$ is $\eta^2+\eta-1$. This is easy to calculate, but the Frobenius map is more of a pain, $\eta^7 = -1-\eta$, so its matrix is now $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\-1&-1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.

Comment: I have to run, but hopefully this is helpful. Feel free to ask for clarification.

Comment: Generally, the Sylow $p$-subgroups for $p$ less than the dimension are weirder.

Comment: I can't understand the intuition and motivation behind your construction. For example, why does the second matrix have connection with Frobenius automorphism, and what is the intuition behind the third matrix? Why does it have order 16? And where comes the semi-product? What is the relation between semi-product and the matrix? Sorry I'm not quite familiar with those concept.

Comment: @hxhxhx88: ok, I added an explanation. I also changed the second generator slightly to more closely fit my explanation.

Comment: I suggest the short version is the best version of my answer. The first paragraph of my intuitive answer is the main intuition. Remember that elements of the Galois group are linear transformations, so they have matrices. Elements of extension fields are linear transformations, so they have matrices. That's really all there is to it. The rest is just checking the details in all the weird cases.

Comment: Is it a conclusion that $\Sym{2} \ltimes (\GL(1,q) \times \GL(1,q))$ and $\Gal(\GF{q^2}/\GF{q})\ltimes \GF{q^2}^\times$ are subgroups of $\GL(2,q)$? I'm wondering why you don't consider something like $\Sym{2} \times (\GL(1,q) \times \GL(1,q))$, so could you provide me some reference about the list of subgroups of $\GL(2,q)$?

Comment: @hxhxhx88: yes. See case 1b and 2b in GL(2,q) in the PDF. I updated it to include an overview (you can skip) and to improve the explanation in several cases.

Comment: OK, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In general we can use wreath product to construct a 2-sylow subgroup, for example, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/127917/ for some details.

But in this special case we can find a beautiful explicit 2-sylow subgroup with exactly 64 elements. Namely

$$\begin{bmatrix}\pm1 & & \\ & \pm1 & \\ & & \pm1 \end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix} & & \pm1\\ & \pm1 & \\ \pm1 & & \end{bmatrix}$$